# Exclude groups in TestNG not in suite

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

I am using a suite file in TestNG to define the tests I want to run. Those suites are triggered with a jenkins job and now I need to make it optional to exclude a specific group or not.

I thought about adding an additional build parameter in jenkins and add a flag to the system properties if this parameter is set like so `-DexcludeMyGroup=true`. In some `@BeforeSuite` or `@BeforeTest` method in my base test I want to check for the property and its value. Depending on that I want to exclude that group from my suite.

I have tried

```
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(XmlTest test) {
  if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("excludeMyGroup"))) {
      test.addExcludedGroup("myGroup");
  }
}
```

as well as

```
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext context) {
  if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("excludeMyGroup"))) {
      cont.getSuite().getXmlSuite().addExcludedGroup("myGroup");
  }
}
```

but both do not work.

I have tried to use the second approach to modify other parameters such as thread count and this works fine using `cont.getSuite().getXmlSuite().setThreadCount(10)` but I have not yet found a way to exclude a specific group besides the suite file. Is there a possibility to exclude this afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple ways to do this:

1. You can also run a TestNG suite programmatically in the main method, and use command line strings to define what groups to exclude (http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/TestNG.html#setExcludedGroups-java.lang.String-):

   `public static void main(String[] args) {
       TestNG tng = new TestNG();
       tng.setExcludedGroups("excludedGroup1, excludedGroup2");
       tng.run();
   }`

Then you could run the class file from the terminal and simply do

```
$ java <classfilename> excludedgroup1 excludedgroup2
```

and write the main function as the below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setExcludedGroups(args[0] + ", " + args[1]);
    tng.run();
}
```

2. TestNG has a command-line switch called `-excludegroups` that will take a comma separated list of the groups you want to exclude, if you run the testng.xml file from the command line: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng.
3. Run it through Maven's surefire plugin. Go to the "excluded groups" part of this page -- you can define them in the pom.xml this way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but all of your approaches require to set the group before running the tests. What I wanted to do is exclude a group after starting the TestNG run but before running the suite. Is there also an approach for that? :)

Comment: @CarleB.Navy I'd have to look into that, but just to clarify, why is it necessary that you want to exclude the group after starting the run but before running the suite? if you know what groups you want to exclude from which suites ahead of time, why wouldn't you exclude those groups ahead of time?

Comment: I think you are right. It does not matter when the groups are excluded. The only problem is I can not exclude them in the suite file, because the test run is triggered by a jenkins job. Same applies for your first approach. I would really appreciate any further suggestions. Thank you very much already

Comment: @CarleB.Navy of course! So if the jenkins job is where the information about what groups to exclude comes in, doesn't that work for both the first and third approach I have provided? In the first approach, couldn't you just run the testng file programmatically through the jenkins job? Forgive me if I misunderstand as I don't know a whole ton about jenkins.